# Trying to transfer my XP virtual box to another computer

Tags: file-transfer

Trying to export my XP virtual box, and get this error message as "VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR
Error 0x80BB0004". I need to export it so I can import it on my new computer.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this thread:

[Vbox Export Error](https://appuals.com/fix-vbox_e_file_error-0x80bb0004/#:%7E:text=This%20suggests%20that%20the%20error,along%20with%20all%20associated%20components.)

> ```
> We investigated this particular issue by looking at various users and the method that they reportedly used to resolve the error message.
> ```
>
> Based on what we were able to gather, there are several fairly common
> scenarios that will trigger this particular error message:
>
> ```
> The .vmdk or .vdi file is corrupt – This particular error is often reported to occur when the user tries to import a virtual appliance
> ```
>
> downloaded over the internet. This can occur due to an incomplete
> download or a network issue.
>
> ```
> vbomxmanage.exe doesn’t have administrative privileges – Another common reason that will trigger this issue is when a component
> ```
>
> involved in the importing or exporting process is missing admin
> rights. This is mostly reported to occur when the user tries to attach
> a virtual disk hosted on a USB drive.
>
> ```
> The machine configuration needs to be updated – The error might also occur because some manual intervention has corrupted your current
> ```
>
> virtual machine configuration. Some users in a similar situation have
> managed to get the issue resolved by recreating the virtual machine
> from scratch in VirtualBox.
>
> ```
> The .vdi or .vmdk file contains bad sectors – Several users have reported that the issue was fixed after they used the CHKDSK utility
> ```
>
> to scan the file for bad sectors. This suggests that the error can
> also occur due to file corruption.
>
> ```
> Corrupted VM VirtualBox installation – A corrupted Windows VirtualBox installation can also trigger this error message. Some
> ```
>
> users have managed to resolve the issue by uninstalling the whole VM
> VirtualBox client along with all associated components.

Several times here, corrupt machine came up, so try restarting the host and guest and see if it will export.

Also make VBOX is OK and current version.

It is reasonable to assert that you may have to build a new XP machine.

Are you keeping proper backups of your virtual machines?